# Sitemap generation with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, sitemap

I need to generate a sitemap in a *Codeigniter* application. I found a few libraries but all of them are outdated and have bug.

**Do I really need a separate library for this?**

I want to know the best way to generate the sitemap in *Codeigniter*.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use my code:

controllers/seo.php

```
Class Seo extends CI_Controller {

    function sitemap()
    {

        $data = "";//select urls from DB to Array
        header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
        $this->load->view("sitemap",$data);
    }
}
```

views/sitemap.php

```
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url();?></loc> 
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>

    <!-- My code is looking quite different, but the principle is similar -->
    <?php foreach($data as $url) { ?>
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url().$url ?></loc>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <?php } ?>

</urlset>
```

add line to config/routes.php

```
$route['seo/sitemap\.xml'] = "seo/sitemap";
```

Sorry if there are some errors in the code, I made it especially for you.
If there are errors, you can fix them easily by understanding the principle.

Comment: What about multiple sitemaps if you have lots of pages/articles?

Comment: Why is this part: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' in <?= ?> echo ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, But It creates an error when submitting it to webmaster account says " 404 error " where as link seems to be working fine. Here is the link check and let me know http://www.infinitietech.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: This is incorrect for sites with more than 1000 paths specified.

Comment: You gave a clue to me. Thanks a lot, my friend!

Answer (score 15):

Must set header :

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url();?></loc> 
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
    <!-- My code is looking quite different, but the principle is similar -->
    <?php foreach($data as $url) { ?>
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url().$url ?></loc>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <?php } ?>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's strongly recommended to add the link of the sitemap to the robots.txt like this:

```
Sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/seo/sitemap
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a CodeIgniter model which enabled you to call functions from a sitemap controller and spit out the XML when you're all done feeding the sitemap.

Feel free to have a look and reuse the CodeIgniter model:

https://github.com/alphabase/CodeIgniter-Sitemap-Generator