# Codeigniter - sitemap error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create sitemap in my codeigniter app following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186051/sitemap-generation-with-codeigniter) answer

Here is my controller method:

```
public function siteMap() {

    $this->load->helper('url');

    $urls = array("test");

    $data['urls'] = $urls;
    $data['frontend'] = $this->getFronendItems();

    $this->load->template('front/site_map.php', $data);

}
```

And my view:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>
```

```
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url() ?></loc> 
    <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<?php foreach($urls as $url) { ?>
<url>
    <loc><?= base_url() . $url ?></loc>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<?php } ?>
```

This raises the following error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 41 at column 8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head

Tried to remove the header and the url is just echoing as a string on the screen. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always place a header above any view files,
usually I place mine at the top of a controller method.

```
public function siteMap() {
   header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");

    $this->load->helper('url');

    $urls = array("test");

    $data['urls'] = $urls;
    $data['frontend'] = $this->getFronendItems();

    $this->load->template('front/site_map.php', $data);

}
```

in the view file, add

```
<?php print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';?>
<?php print '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';?>

<url>
  <loc><?=base_url()?></loc> 
  <priority>1.0</priority>
</url>

<?php foreach($urls as $url) {
    ?>
    <url>
      <loc><?=base_url().$url?></loc>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <?php 
} 
?>

<?php print '</urlset>';?>
```

This is exactly how I do my sitemap.

Comment: Still getting the same error :(  I`m using template because I have common header and footer for all views.

Comment: what is on line 41 at column 8 of the page?