# In codeigniter, I am using page slugs, now I want to generate sitemap dynamically. Url get changed from admin then sitemap links should be updated?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter project, I am using page slugs for `SEO`, but now I want to generate sitemap dynamically. When Url get changed from admin then sitemap links should be updated.

I have implemented static sitemap temporarily using "online sitemap generator portals". But now I have to implement dynamic sitemap according to current url structures.

I google it most but they are fetching urls from database & generating "sitemap.xml". **But in my case, urls changing once page slug is changed from back-end.**  So I am unable to go through database.

I tried this solution:
[Sitemap generation with Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186051/sitemap-generation-with-codeigniter)

But in my case, once page slug gets changed then sitemap is not affecting according to above code snippet.

please suggest me the solution??

Comment: So just trigger a new sitemap when the admin changes a URL... what's the problem?  Also, you need to make an attempt and show us some code... not just come here asking for codez.

Comment: 1. Admin updates URL and this saves into db table called `sitemap`
2. After this occurs you regenerate the `sitemap.xml` and/or modify it and save it.